# How to backup specific application?

Tags: backup

using 12.04.

is it possible to have backup of particular application ?

i mean I don't want all applications and I just want one single application as a backup along with its configurations or settings what I made .

so from what areas I've to collect the backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It heavily depends on the application.

If you have installed the application from the Software Center, then I guess you will not have a problem re-downloading and re-installing it through there, you just want to keep your settings. If this really the case, then you have to look under your home folder.

The first place to look is under `~/.config/Application_Name` and under `~/.Application_Name`.

Usually, if you backup these folders you will successfully save the configurations of your applications. But, unless you are more specific about your application, I cannot search and see myself.

Comment: hi actually i want to back up the application along with its settings . so you gave me the solution for configurations as we know . Thank you for that +1 .

Comment: So, can't you save the settings and re-install the application? Everything would be like it is.